# Ubuntu volume control slider moves strangely

Tags: 14.04, ubuntu-sdk, volume-control

I have a really strange problem with the volume control of Ubuntu 14.04. When I move the slider it jumps from side to side and does not follow my mouse pointer. When I remove my mouse pointer from the volume slider, it moves itself randomly.

Eventually I realised that the problem occurs when I install the Ubuntu SDK. I have no idea how to fix it. I searched all over the internet for a solution, but nothing helped. I don't want to uninstall the Ubuntu SDK because I want to write programs with it.

I recorded a video of the strange problem - it is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JpkY1cPpqaI).

Comment: What desktop are you using in the video? It does not look like Unity.

Comment: It is Unity with Numix theme and transparent panel. I just hided the starter to have more space.

Comment: I have the same problem. The volume slider in the top menu bar jumps strangely around after I have adjusted the volume. The same thing happens within the audio control module in Settings. It even happens for input and for output.

Comment: Please confirm this bug [here] if it affects you as well. [here]: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-sound/+bug/1343962

Comment: It's better to look for these issues in launchpad and not to ask them on Askubuntu, as @python mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Use synaptic and mark "for complete removal"! indicator -sound and all unity8-* and all libmir* packages. Apply the changes.... then sudo apt-get --purge autoremove, then reboot, then install indicator-sound then reboot. And it works correctly. (next unity-control-center for valid control panel view)

Source: Marat solutions from [bug report link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-sound/+bug/1343962) provided by @python