# Strange bug with sound slider

Tags: 14.04, sound, bug-reporting, volume-control, indicator-sound

I have a strange bug with the sound slider in Ubuntu 14.04. This problem was described in [Ubuntu volume control slider moves strangely](https://askubuntu.com/questions/475385/ubuntu-volume-control-slider-moves-strangely) too, but with no answer and the author was using another desktop — I'm using default Unity. I can confirm that the slider bugged after the installation of Ubuntu SDK, so I think we can be sure this causes the problem. I've uninstalled Ubuntu SDK with these commands:

```
$ sudo apt-get autoremove ubuntu-sdk
$ sudo apt-get --purge remove ubuntu-sdk
$ sudo apt-get autoclean
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
$ sudo apt-get -f install
```

but the slider is still buggy. I've made a GIF to show what's happening.

[image: Scrolling up]

Here I'm scrolling (mouse, touchpad; yes, I've checked another mouse) **only** up, a few times. After some time I clicked the sound bar icon and stopped scrolling instantly, but as you can see it moves itself randomly. The same happens if I scroll **only** down as well.

This problem occurs only with the desktop sound slider (notification slider). There are no problems with scrolling other things in the whole system. In Ubuntu Sound Settings, everything is fine with the slider too.
I have three questions:

1. How to get rid of this problem?
2. Have I uninstalled Ubuntu SDK correctly? What more can I remove to be sure that every file related or changed during installation of SDK has been removed?
3. What is the best way to inform Ubuntu SDK/Ubuntu developers of this bug?

Please confirm this bug here if it affects you as well: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-sound/+bug/1343962